# PHP Image hashing accuracy suggestion

Tags: php, image, hash, duplicates, imagick

I'm trying to add image hash to the database.

My problem is that I have 3million images and some of them are 99.999+% the same. For example both **imageA.jpg** and **imageB.jpg** have the same resolution 800x600, but lets say **imageB.jpg** have 10 different pixels:

800x600 = 480000 total pixels;

(480000 - 10 pixels difference) / 48000 total pixels = 0.9999791666666667 similarity

To reduce duplicates I wrote PHP class prototype. Everything is working fine, not perfectly, but just fine. The main problem is, that **->recreateFile()** function every time creates a bit different image even if I'm setting the maximum quality.

I'm looking for solution to stabilize all the pixels even if I would recreate the image 100 times.

Any other better solution/ideas to reduce my duplicated images?

My PHP class code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class HashImage
 * @package App\Cryptography
 */
class HashImage
{
    /**
     *
     */
    const IMAGE_PIXELS = 32;
    /**
     *
     */
    const IMAGE_QUALITY = 100;
    /**
     *
     */
    const IMAGE_FORMAT = 'jpg';
    /**
     *
     */
    const IMAGE_ALGORITHM = 'sha256';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $file;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $hash;

    /**
     * HashImage constructor.
     * @param string $file
     */
    public function __construct(string $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    public function getHash(): string
    {
        $this
            ->recreateFile()
            ->setHash(1)
            ->setHash(2)
            ->setHash(0);
        return hash(self::IMAGE_ALGORITHM, $this->hash);
    }


    /**
     * @param int $type
     * @return self
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    private function setHash(int $type): self
    {
        $image = new \Imagick($this->file);
        $image->setImageDepth(8);
        $image->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
        $image->quantizeImage(15, \Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 255, false, false);
        $image->setImageFormat('PNG');
        if ($type === 1) {
            $width = self::IMAGE_PIXELS;
            $height = self::IMAGE_PIXELS / 2;
        } elseif ($type === 2) {
            $width = self::IMAGE_PIXELS / 2;
            $height = self::IMAGE_PIXELS;
        } else {
            $width = self::IMAGE_PIXELS;
            $height = self::IMAGE_PIXELS;
        }
        $image->cropThumbnailImage($width, $height);
        $img = imagecreatefromstring($image->getImageBlob());
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
                $colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));
                $this->hash .= round((round((round((round(($colors['red'] + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
                    . round((round((round((round(($colors['green'] + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
                    . round((round((round((round(($colors['blue'] + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) + 1) / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return self
     */
    private function optimizeFile(): self
    {
        exec('/usr/bin/jpegoptim --strip-all --all-progressive ' . $this->file);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return self
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    private function recreateFile(): self
    {
        $image = new \Imagick($this->file);
        $image->setImageFormat(self::IMAGE_FORMAT);
        $image->setCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $image->setCompressionQuality(self::IMAGE_QUALITY);
        $image->writeImage($this->file);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the images to be re-created or hashed absolutely 100% losslessly you cannot use JPEG! Different versions of the library, different implementations, different quality parameters will result in different pixels.

Comment: I agree with the library difference, but if the library is the same and the source file is the same, why after resizing them both of the images have different random pixels?

Comment: Your `setHash` method invokes encoding & decoding between ImageMagick + GD libraries, as well as quantization & rounding. So much data is being thrown out, and as @MarkSetchell pointed out, your already have an accuracy disadvantage when working with losslessly format. Also note; `Imagick` already calculates this hash with [getImageSignature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagesignature.php).

Comment: getImageSignature way more accurate than my method, I want to mark some images as a duplicate, even if there is <100px difference in total. meanwhile getImageSignature marks such a thing as a difference, even if I'm resizing 1920x1080 to 10x10@255 colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this,
current solution code:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Cryptography;
/**
 * Class HashImage
 * @package App\Cryptography
 */
class HashImage
{
    /**
     * Hashing accuracy
     */
    const HASHING_PIXELS = 64;
    /**
     * Return encryption algorithm
     */
    const HASHING_ALGORITHM = 'sha256';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $file;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $hash;

    /**
     * HashImage constructor.
     * @param string $file
     */
    public function __construct(string $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    public function getHash(): string
    {
        $this
            ->setHash(1)
            ->setHash(2)
            ->setHash(0);
        return hash(self::HASHING_ALGORITHM, $this->hash);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $type
     * @return self
     * @throws \ImagickException
     */
    private function setHash(int $type): self
    {
        $image = new \Imagick($this->file);
        $image->setImageFormat('PNG');
        $image->setImageDepth(8);
        $image->setGravity(\Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
        $width = $height = self::HASHING_PIXELS;
        if ($type === 1) {
            $height = self::HASHING_PIXELS / 2;
        } elseif ($type === 2) {
            $width = self::HASHING_PIXELS / 2;
        }
        $image->cropThumbnailImage($width, $height);
        $img = imagecreatefromstring($image->getImageBlob());
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
                $colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));
                $this->hash .= $colors['red'] . $colors['green'] . $colors['blue'];
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```